# Bootstrap Row CSS issues with IE compatibility

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The site is bestofhemingway.com, and I am obviously just getting my feet wet with this whole thing. The site looks okay on Chrome, but the row is not lining up correctly in Explorer. I have been researching and fiddling and it looks to be a problem with .container or .row or the column class in bootstrap.css.

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

That's all in the `.row` class. One row in the wordpress page looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"><h2 class="box-title"><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0743297334" rel="nofollow noreferrer">The Sun Also Rises</a>

<div class="col-md-8"> </div></div></div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"><h2 class="box-title"><a href="link" ></a></div>

<div class="col-md-8"><h7 class="box-lang">Text</div></div>
```

---

Why `.row` is not working in IE?

Comment: the closing div for col-md-4 is inside the col-md-8, there's no such element as h7 and besides you're not closing it either.

Answer (score 2):

Properly indented, your code is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2 class="box-title">
            <a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743297334">The Sun Also Rises</a>
        <div class="col-md-8"> </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2 class="box-title">
            <a href="link" ></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h7 class="box-lang">Text
    </div>
</div>
```

This reveals several issues.

- Your first `col-md-8` is within your first `col-md-4` rather than being a sibling element.
- You're using the non-existent `h7` tag.
- You're not closing your `h` tags, leaving the browser to do its own interpretation.